# This в jquery

Tags: jquery, sortable

Здравствуйте!
Возникла проблема в следующей задачи:
Есть некоторое кол-во полей с определёнными **id**.
Есть изображение, с неким **id**, которое находится в определённом поле со своим id. 
Изображения можно перетаскивать из одного поля в другое по определённым правилам. Родительский id текущий картинку вытаскиваю через **$(this).parent.attr('id')**; 
Зная родительский id, в котором находимся сейчас, и, зная id изображения (**$(this).attr('id')**), узнаю, куда можем перетащить изображение.

Если родительский id изображения имеет определенные значения, то при клике на изображения, мы меняем содержимое родителя изображения, т.е. заменяем само изображение на другое, а также меняем его id.

По задумке новое изображение мы также должны перетаскивать. Не могу проверить id нового изображения. Т.е. если у нас, например, было два изображения и одно из них заменилось после перетаскивания на определённое поле, то при клике на изображение мне надо проверить его id.

Для изображения, которое мы не меняли **$(this).attr('id')** срабатывает, а вот для нового уже нет. 
Понимаю, что проблема весьма расплывчата, если что-то непонятно в вопросе - пишите, постараюсь разъяснить!  :)

Почему не срабатывает **$(this).attr('id')** и как можно вытащить id при клике на изображение?

Comment: &nbsp;

    $(this).parent.attr('id')

скобки?

Answer (score 2):

Это какой-то неверный подход. 
Задумайтесь. У Вас есть множество одинаковых объектов. Значит уже с ними по отдельности работать нет смылса. Это уже массив.
Как его сделать? Ну можно по класу. Каждому элементу добавляем любой css класс. Я назову его myUniqClass.
Получается у меня

```
<div id="parent">
    <image class="myUniqClass" src="imh1.jpeg">
    <image class="myUniqClass" src="imh2.jpeg">
    <image class="myUniqClass" src="imh3.jpeg">
</div>
```

Двигаемся дальше

```
$(".myUniqClass", "#parent").each(function(){
    var th = jQuery(this);
    console.log(th);
    th.on('click', function(){ alert(th.attr('src')) });

});
```

`on` - для примера навесил.

Comment: Понимаете какая штука. Один родитель - один дочерний элемент.Я пытаюсь написать шахматную доску, на которой фигуры можно двигать по правилам. Для движения использовал плагин sortable. При нажатии мышкой на ловлю текущее поле и высчитываю куда можем пойти. Для каждой фигуры своя формула. А вот с превращением пешки проблема. Там где была пешки - становится выбранная фигура. А id этой новой фигуры на нажатии на неё мышкой не вытаскивается. Например был ферзь, поставили ещё одного. Старый ферзь просчитывается без проблем, а с новым косяк - не могу поймать его текущий id абсолютно не на каком поле

Comment: На возможность перетаскивания фигуры влияет только текущее поле и, собственно, вид фигуры (конь, слон)... И если на доске два слона, то уж по одинаковому они не как ходить не могу. И тогда зачем им общий класс? 
Ваша идея мне ясна, возможно, я не верно выразил свою проблему...

Comment: у вас id это тип фигуры ? это не правильно.

Comment: Да, id это тип фигуры? Почему не верно?
Сейчас проработал весь код, ошибка оказалась чуть раньше. Не срабатывает функция, обрабатывающая данные и совершающая перемещение... 

$('.board div span img').mousedown(function (){/*код*/});

Comment: потому-что id должен  быть уникальным на документ. а например пешек 8

Comment: А зачем мне уникальный id? Ведь при щелчке на фигуру я знаю её тип и где она находится.

Comment: уникальный id это по стандарту. лучше используйте data() для того чтобы задавать метаданные DOM объектов.

Comment: eicto, спасибо, буду знать. Но у меня всё-же проблема заключалась в другом...

Comment: ну а ваша проблема решается через data, картинку  когда на доску помещаете, приделайте к ней .data() с описанием  фигуры, ходы там цвет, в .data() клеточки ставьте ссылку на фигуру которая там стоит. делайте ходы в массиве 8x8 а не на экране, не привязывайтесь к DOM, он обманчив, как и реальный мир.

Comment: @chessinvin Как все запутано....а в js классов нет?